# How to change population variables with different distributions during run-time in AnyLogic

Tags: variables, parameters, distribution, anylogic

Building my first model here and I am enjoying the process. I have run into my last problem to overcome before it is done....

I am trying to add radio buttons that can change the distribution within a variable of a population as its being created. However, when I do so, it only picks one number for the variable from a distribution specified - resulting in all agents doing the exact same thing when being created.

How do I fix this?

This is the code within my radio buttons. A variable for agent priority within the 'order' agent is supposed to change according to a distribution every time its created. I want to change the whole distribution with a clock of a button.

```
if (value == 0) {
Prioritymanipulation = uniform(0, 51);
}
else if (value == 1) {
set_Prioritymanipulation (triangular(0, 51, 30));
}
else if (value == 2) {
Prioritymanipulation = triangular (0, 20, 51);
}
else if (value == 3) {
Prioritymanipulation = triangular (0, 40, 51);
}
```

Is there a way to do this without custom distributions? Whenever I try it I get a whole bunch of errors about not being able to convert from a double...

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: prioritymanipulation is not a distribution, it's just a random draw of that distribution... you need to define your distribution when it's needed and not on the radio button.. but more info is needed to tell you exactly what to do.

Comment: Hmm so what information do you need? Is there no way to change distributions through a button?

Comment: I may have figured it out... instead of changing entire distributions, you can use buttons to change numbers within the distributions. eg. `triangular (0, main.variableconnectedtobutton, 80)`